# NSMutableArray not retaining?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm having some issues with my Arrays, I hoped anyone here can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I have 3 arrays: tmpAnswersArray, localAnswersArray & finalAnswersArray.
I also have a method to shuffle a given array in the same class.

The first NSLog shows the count for the localAnswersArray is 6 (how it supposed to be).

The third NSLog shows the localAnswersArray count is 0, even though I didn't change anything in that array.

```
localAnswersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  localAnswersArray = [self shuffleArray:tmpAnswersArray];

  [tmpAnswersArray release];

  NSLog(@"Shuffled localAnswersArray (count = %d) & removed tmpAnswersArray",[localAnswersArray count]);

  finalAnswersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"init finalAnswersArray");


  for (int arrayCount = 0; arrayCount < 6; arrayCount++) {
   NSLog(@"TEST ---> %d",[localAnswersArray count]);
   [finalAnswersArray addObject:[localAnswersArray objectAtIndex:arrayCount]];
  }
```

Is the first line of this code also retains the array?

Do I have to retain it manually somehow?

Why is the array count drops to 0 all of a sudden?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Change %d (double) to %i (integer). The count property is an integer. Do you still get zero for the count? Also, does the application crash? If not, you have elements in `localAnswersArray`.

Comment: A lot of this depends on what your shuffleArray method does. The first two lines are a problem too (you're creating an array then assigning another object to that variable - memory leak).

Comment: @Evan: `%d` is not "double", but "decimal". "double" is printed with `%e`/`%f`/`%g`.

Comment: @KennyTM: Actually `%d` is an integer. We were both incorrect. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: I feel that there is code missing... and your first line alloc's a new array that is leaked with line 2.

Comment: @Evan: No it's just you. NSLog's formatting inherited from C's `printf`, where both `%d` and `%i` means "the `int` argument is converted to signed **decimal** in the style *[−]dddd* " (C99 §7.19.6.1/8). It means decimal because an integer can be in octal `%o` or hexadecimal `%x` as well. The distinction is important when used in `scanf` because `%d` only allows **decimal** number but `%i` allows oct and hex as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to review the [Memory Management Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

```
localAnswersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
localAnswersArray = [self shuffleArray:tmpAnswersArray];
```

You create an array (that you own), then immediately replace it with a different array.

And it would seem that your entire block of code could be replaced with this:

```
finalAnswersArray = [[self shuffleArray:tmpAnswersArray] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do need to review some memory management rules... thanks!

Comment: You were right, Dave. I replaced the entire block of code with the line you suggested and it works, but it doesn't shuffle the array. I'll look into it further. Thanks!